# How to wait for a /dev/video0 before starting a service

Tags: systemd, udev

I can write unit files, which depend on a mount, because I can list them and then add to `Requires=xxx`, such as:

```
# systemctl list-units | grep data
mount-data.service    loaded active exited    Manage the data partition
```

What I am trying to do is to make service start when webcam is plugged into device. `systemctl list-units | grep video0` returns nothing. Can someone explain me in simple terms, what do I do to ensure that? What I do want to happen is start service when `/dev/video0`, `/dev/video1`, etc appear.

I got a clue from [this post](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2012-January/160917.html), that I will need to write a udev rule, but I have no idea what exactly needs to be done here. Help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured this out. First, add following line(s) to one of the files in udev rule folder, I used `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules`

```
KERNEL=="video0", SYMLINK="video0", TAG+="systemd"
KERNEL=="video1", SYMLINK="video1", TAG+="systemd"
```

Then you can bind to video device(s) in service unit file:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=dev-video0.device
After=dev-video0.device
```